# Adding a keyboard layout for 50 domain users

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, keyboard-layout, windows-domain

There are around 50 domain users who need a new keyboard layout added to their Windows desktops.

Is there a way to do that without going to each computer?

Comment: [This looks promising](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/6281.how-to-set-the-keyboard-layout-through-group-policy-gpo.aspx), but I can’t verify right now.

Comment: This might be more appropriate on [sf].

Comment: @Mokubai You think so? I thought this isn't a "question about server, networking, or related infrastructure administration".

Comment: Their [help](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) states "Server Fault is for questions about managing information technology systems in a business environment." And "managing the hardware or software of servers, workstations, storage or networks" as well as "tools used for administering, monitoring, or automating these".